# fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb") FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система

В `main.py` картинка открывается нормально, но когда я пытаюсь запустить тесты, он её не видит. Я пробовал создать `__init__.py`, менял путь до файла, но ничего не помогает.

Примерная структура проекта:

```
────project
    │
    ├───src
    │       images.jpg
    │       main.py
    │
    └───tests
            test.py
```

```py
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images.jpg"))
```

Comment: Не видит. Потому что в директории `tests` нет картинки. Либо измените путь, либо скопируйте картинку в папку `tests`

Comment: nomnoms,если я делаю путь /src/images.jpg,то не работает уже и в main

Comment: nomnoms,я знаю что можно просто копирнуть файлы,но не хочу этих костылей,вот в чем проблема

Answer (score 0):

Изменить путь в файле `test.py`:

```py
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('../src/images.jpg'))
```

---

Ошибка возникает потому, что Вы указываете неверный путь до изображения.

[Пути](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83) бывают двух видов: абсолютные и относительные. Путь `images.jpg` — относительный. То есть скрипт будет искать файл в той директории, из которой Вы его запускаете. В Вашем случае скрипт ищет файл `tests\images.jpg`, которого нет.

У Вас есть 3 пути:

1. Скопировать изображение в `tests`
2. Указать абсолютный путь
3. Исправить относительный путь

Предлагаю исправить относительный. Сложности здесь могут возникнуть только с тем, как подняться в родительскую папку. Для этого есть комбинация из двух точек — `..`.